# bash alias autocomplete with extensions

Tags: bash, autocomplete

so i have this in my .bashrc file:

```
alias open="vi"
```

So, when I am programming in java, if I type "vi Te[TAB]" it will auto complete to "vi Test.java" not "vi Test.class" or "vi Test". This is not the same case if I do it with my alias "open". How can I fix that?

Comment: Test.class is not editable

Comment: Why are you defining an alias that's longer than the original command?

Answer (score 4):

Run `eval $(complete -p vi | sed 's/vi/open/')` in your `.bashrc`. It will make `open` use the exact same completion options as `vi`.

Comment: I don't get it. Now I have

alias open="vi"
eval $(complete -p vi | sed 's/vi/open/')

but it still doesnt work

Comment: (Make sure to have alias=.. and eval .. on two separate lines, and to source your bashrc again after the edit.)

Comment: What is the output of `complete -p vi` in your shell ?